# The origin '' did not find '' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin image resource at ''

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, cors, openlayers

i use open layer map with mvc project , 
with cdn :

```
<script src="https://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

while i need to get location i have function

> getlocation

```
function getLocation() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var loc_obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                if (loc_obj) {
                    usersLocationUpdated(loc_obj.latitude, loc_obj.longitude, loc_obj.added_time, loc_obj.located_time);
                } else {
                     if (!mapLayer) {
                            mapLayer = new OpenLayers.Map("myMap");

                        }
                    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                    mapLayer.addLayer(markers);
                     
                }
            }
            
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "../api/tracking/....", false);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

the map working well in browser chrome 
as appears in image : 
[image: Image Success]

but in IE,Edge and safari the map appears as image attached
[image: Image Fail]

when check console in failing browser (Edge and safari)
i have the error :

[CORS] The origin 'My web site ' did not find 'My web site '
in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin image resource at 'http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/16/38663/27093.p' 

i try many solution with send request as  :

```
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Any help . !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSM is CORS enabled but most browsers will reject CORS from an http url if the application is running on a https site.  OpenLayers 2 defaults to an http address for OSM so try specifying it with an https address

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
  "OpenStreetMap",
  ["https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
   "https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
   "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"]
)
```

Comment: i edit my code with 
 mapLayer = new OpenLayers.Map("myMap",
                
                                ["https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                                    "https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                                    "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"]);
                        }
but still same error

Comment: Changing `new OpenLayers.Map` will not fix it.  If you are using OSM there should be a line somewhere in your code `new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM`